# When the parent is float:left and the child is fixed, how to set position?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I would like to change the picture above as shown below.

[image]

Please refer to the code below.

I'm wondering how to solve this problem without 'padding-left, margin-left'

```css
.nav-wrap {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: -2px;
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
  float: left;
}

.sidebar-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 380px;
  padding-top: 95px;
  padding-bottom: 95px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  z-index: 10;
}

.content-wrap {
  width: 66.66666666666666%;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 45px 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrap">
  <div class="sidebar-nav">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrap">

</div>
```

Comment: Do you really want your sidebar to be positioned: fixed? That is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](https://jsbin.com/kajejuk/edit?html,css,output) instead - I've created a barebone for you without bootstrap. You can start from here.

```
  <ul id="mainWrapper">
    <li class="left-wrap">

      <div class="menuList">

        <ul>
          <li>Menu 1</li>
          <li>Menu 2</li>
          <li>Menu 3</li>
          <li>Menu 4</li>
        </ul>

      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="right-wrap">
      Content here...

    </li>
  </ul>
```